# How to attach a source for a file in java

Tags: java

Whenever I start my programm this shows in the debug window up :

SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(FileDescriptor, boolean, boolean) line: not available [native method]

It says that the source is not found and i should attach something.
How can i solve this ?

Comment: Eclipse-Java EE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `SocketChannelImpl` is in the package `sun.nio.ch` which is a non-public package and hence doesn't provide debuggable java source code. You are trying to debug the call to the method `checkConnect` the source code of which is not available for this reason. So that's why Eclipse is giving you this error. You cannot debug this source code.